# Is there a way to use TLS with sdl_net?

Tags: c++, sockets, sdl-2, tls1.2, sdl-net

I need to send an email with a gmail account in C++. This email will contain text and also attachments. Right now i'm using sdl_net to deal with socket on multiple platform but i have to work with TLS to send the email. 
 So my question is, is there a way to keep sdl_net to deal with socket and do a TLS connection at the same time.

```
//This function is used to create the log file
int smtpLog(std::fstream* file, std::string* text)
{
    int len = text->length();
    file->seekg(std::fstream::end);
    file->write(text->c_str(), len);
    return 0;
}

int send(TCPsocket* socket, const char *message, std::fstream* file)
{
    int len = strlen(message);
    int result = SDLNet_TCP_Send(*socket, message, len);
    std::string error_message("Failed to send message to the server: ");


    if (result < len)
    {
        error_message.append(SDLNet_GetError());
        smtpLog(file, &error_message);
        SDLNet_TCP_Close(*socket);
        return 1;
    }
    smtpLog(file, &std::string("Client: "));
    smtpLog(file, &std::string(message));
    smtpLog(file, &std::string("\n"));
    return 0;
}

int receive(TCPsocket* socket, void* data, std::fstream* file)
{
    int result = SDLNet_TCP_Recv(*socket, data, 1024);
    if (result <= 0)
    {
        std::string error_message("There were an error: ");
        error_message.append(SDLNet_GetError());
        smtpLog(file, &error_message);
        return 1;
    }
    smtpLog(file, &std::string("Server: "));
    smtpLog(file, &std::string(reinterpret_cast<char*>(data)));
    smtpLog(file, &std::string("\n"));

    return 0;
}

//This is the main function 
int sendEmail()
{
    if(SDLNet_Init() == -1)
    {
        SDL_Log("SDLNet failed to init: %s", SDLNet_GetError());
        return 1;
    }

    IPaddress address;
    TCPsocket socket;
    char received_message[1024] = {};
    char received_message2[1024] = {};

    if (SDLNet_ResolveHost(&address, "smtp.gmail.com", 587) == -1)
    {
        SDL_Log("Failed to load SDL_Net: %s", SDLNet_GetError());
        return 1;
    }

    if (!(socket = SDLNet_TCP_Open(&address)))
    {
        SDL_Log("Failed to open TCP: %s", SDLNet_GetError());
        return 1;
    }
    std::fstream* log_file = new std::fstream("log.txt", std::fstream::in | std::fstream::out | std::fstream::app);

    //Hello command
    send(&socket, "EHLO 192.168.1.1 \r\n", log_file);
    receive(&socket, &received_message, log_file);
    SDL_Delay(10);
    memset(&received_message, 0, 1024);

    receive(&socket, &received_message, log_file);
    memset(&received_message, 0, 1024);

    SDL_Delay(10);
    send(&socket, "STARTTLS \r\n", log_file);
    receive(&socket, &received_message, log_file);


    SDLNet_TCP_Close(socket);
    log_file->close();
    SDLNet_Quit();

    delete log_file;
    return 0;
}
```

Here is the produced log:

```
Client: EHLO 192.168.1.1 


Server: 220 smtp.gmail.com ESMTP y75sm284351wme.27 - gsmtp


Server: 250-smtp.gmail.com at your service, [ip-address]

250-SIZE 35882577

250-8BITMIME

250-STARTTLS

250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES

250-PIPELINING

250-CHUNKING

250 SMTPUTF8


Client: STARTTLS 


Server: 220 2.0.0 Ready to start TLS
```